# why is itunes not acknowledging my gift card credit?

Tags: itunes-store

I have $50 of store credit to iTunes from gift cards for my birthday and when I go to buy anything it's trying to charge my debit card, not my iTunes gift cards.  is there something I have to do to change that or what?

Answer (score 1):

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201209

That should answer your question. ;)

Comment: sorry but it didn't